# Displaying Arabic numbers in Google chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, encoding, arabic

I setup the windows region settings as national as Arabic language, and when I am using the internet explorer it display the numbers in Arabic,   but when using chrome it display numbers in English.

I want to know where is the problem of showing the Arabic numbers in chrome, and I have tried to make my default display language as Arabic and nothing happened ...

Comment: Can you provide an example? I assume you are talking about a website. Is that so? In that case, can you show us a sample of the code?

Comment: @opalenzuela yes it's a website ,, and it's wordpress ,, and the database is utf-8

Comment: then we need to see the code. It's probably an encoding problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is convert numbers to Arabic language ...
all u need to embed it to your WordPress website

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    var map = 
                [
                "&\#1632;","&\#1633;","&\#1634;","&\#1635;","&\#1636;",
                "&\#1637;","&\#1638;","&\#1639;","&\#1640;","&\#1641;"
                ]

    document.body.innerHTML = 
        document.body.innerHTML.replace(
            /\d(?=[^<>]*(<|$))/g,
            function($0) { return map[$0] }
        );
})
```

Comment: thx but there is a problem ,,,,, any hyperlink doesn't open when i embed this code